# Enviar parámetros usando Segue

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uitableview, uicollectionview

El día de hoy quiero enviar un id proveniente de un elemento de una collectionView y mi intención es recibir dicho parámetro en otra UITableViewController y después, buscar en una API utilizando el parámetro obtenido, muchas gracias, he intentado lo siguiente pero solo recibo el valor inicializado de la variable

MI ORIGEN

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "detail" {
        if let vcDestino = segue.destination as? ArtistDetailTableViewController {
            let cell = sender as! UICollectionViewCell
            let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
            let valor = artistas[(indexPath?.row)!].idArtista
            vcDestino.buscarAr = valor
        }
    }
}
```

MI DESTINO

```
class ArtistDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{


var buscarAr: Int = 0
// MARK: - viewDidLoad

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getArtista(_id: buscarAr)

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Espero esto te ayude.

Primero programaticamente cuando selecciones una celda pasa por el parametro sender lo que te sea mas conveniente:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

  performSegue(withIdentifier: "detail", sender: indexPath.item) // recuerda usar el idexPath.item ya que utilizas un collectionView

}
// y en tu funcion prepare for segue //


 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     if segue.identifier == "detail" {
        if let vcDestino = segue.destination as? ArtistDetailTableViewController {
          if let index = sender as? Int{
              let valor = artistas[index].idArtista
              vcDestino.buscarAr = valor
          }  
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que intentar lo siguiente...

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "detail" {
            if let index = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first {
            //Configurar tu objecto
            }
        }
    }
```